# Add columns to a dataframe based on values from a list

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i"), 
           B=c("1","1","1","2","2","2","3","3","3"), 
           C=c(0.1,0.2,0.4,0.1,0.5,0.7,0.1,0.2,0.5))

> df
  A B   C 
1 a 1 0.1 
2 b 1 0.2 
3 c 1 0.4 
4 d 2 0.1 
5 e 2 0.5 
6 f 2 0.7 
7 g 3 0.1 
8 h 3 0.2 
9 i 3 0.5
```

And a list with elements which names match to `df$B`, i.e, these values are permutations of values from `df$B`, here is an example:

```
 ll <- list('1'=c(0.1,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.1,0.4),
            '2'=c(0.1,0.1,0.5,0.7,0.5,0.7),
            '3'=c(0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.5))
```

Is there any way to create new columns in the dataframe `df` that corresponds to the values of `df$B` in list `ll` but at the same time they are *sampled* values from `ll`? 
Here is a desired output for a better explanation

```
> df
  A B   C  P1  P2  P3  P4  P5  P6
1 a 1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.4 0.2 0.1 0.4
2 b 1 0.2 0.1 0.4 0.2 0.1 0.2 0.2
3 c 1 0.4 0.4 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.1 0.4
4 d 2 0.1 0.1 0.7 0.5 0.1 0.7 0.1
5 e 2 0.5 0.7 0.5 0.1 0.7 0.1 0.5
6 f 2 0.7 0.5 0.5 0.7 0.1 0.7 0.1
7 g 3 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.5
8 h 3 0.2 0.2 0.1 0.5 0.2 0.2 0.5
9 i 3 0.5 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.1 0.5 0.2
```

Comment: You must mean sampled values rather than "permuted values"? Permutation change the order of a vector but not the membership.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this maybe:

```
cbind(df, t(sapply(df$B, function(i, l) sample(l[[as.character(i)]]), l = ll))

#   A B   C   1   2   3   4   5   6
# 1 a 1 0.1 0.2 0.4 0.1 0.1 0.4 0.1
# 2 b 1 0.2 0.4 0.2 0.4 0.1 0.1 0.1
# 3 c 1 0.4 0.4 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.1 0.4
# 4 d 2 0.1 0.1 0.7 0.5 0.5 0.1 0.7
# 5 e 2 0.5 0.7 0.1 0.5 0.1 0.5 0.7
# 6 f 2 0.7 0.5 0.1 0.7 0.1 0.5 0.7
# 7 g 3 0.1 0.5 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.2 0.2
# 8 h 3 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.1 0.5 0.2 0.1
# 9 i 3 0.5 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.5 0.2 0.2
```

Or please clarify "permuted" if I misunderstood.

Comment: thanks @flodel, the `l[[as.character(i)]]` is to match between values from `df$b` and names of `ll`, isn't it?

Comment: thanks, that is what I was looking for, `apply` functions are very useful. Thanks again @flodel

Comment: Should you add `replace=TRUE` to the `sample` call? Notice in the desired result that the frequencies of the sampled `ll` components don't always match the original frequencies.

Comment: @thelatemail, might be. In that case, I wouldn't call it a permutation though, like DWin pointed out. Not sure if the OP's wording was wrong or his expected output.

Comment: Actually, I want that each row that matches a `df$B` value corresponds to a random permutation of `ll`, and, yes, I would like the original frequencies are pretty the same, should I add `replace=TRUE` to the `sample` call?

Comment: That will depend on the meaning of "pretty the same"... A random permutation means you take the vector and shuffle it, so so you have the exactly the same items but in a different order. If that's what you want then don't add `replace = TRUE`.

Comment: If I want the exact frequencies of the values distributed in `ll`, should I add `replace=TRUE` to the `sample` call?

Comment: well then you are indeed looking for a random permutation. But note that the expected output you gave in your question is not a random permutation. E.g. row 2 of your output has three `0.2` while `ll["1"]]` only has one. Many rows of your output have that issue, hence the confusion...