# Add columns to a list of data.frames

Tags: r, dataframe

This is a similar question to an old post of mine [Add columns to a dataframe based on values from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17286813/add-columns-to-a-dataframe-based-on-values-from-a-list).

Now, I would like to use the solution provide it, but instead of applying it to a single data.frame, I'd like to use it on a list of data.frame.

Briefly, I have a list of data.frames that looks like this:

```
df <- list(data.frame(A=c("a","b","c"), 
                      B=c("1","2","1"), 
                      C=c(0.1,0.7,0.4)), 
            data.frame(A=c("d","e","f"), 
                       B=c("2","2","3"), 
                      C=c(0.5,0.1,0.5)), 
            data.frame(A=c("g","h","i"), 
                       B=c("3","1","2"), 
                       C=c(0.2,0.1,0.5)))
```

And a list with elements which names match to `df$B`, i.e, these values are permutations of values from `df$B`, here is an example:

```
 ll <- list('1'=c(0.1,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.1,0.4),
            '2'=c(0.1,0.1,0.5,0.7,0.5,0.7),
            '3'=c(0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.5))
```

I want to create a new list of data.frames but with new columns in each dataframe of list `df` that correspond to the values of `df$B` in list `ll` but at the same time they are *sampled* values from `ll`? 
Here is a desired output for a better explanation

```
> list.df
[[1]]
  A B   C  P1  P2  P3  P4  P5  P6
1 a 1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.4 0.2 0.1 0.4
2 b 2 0.7 0.1 0.5 0.7 0.1 0.5 0.1
3 c 1 0.4 0.4 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.1 0.4

[[2]]
  A B   C  P1  P2  P3  P4  P5  P6
1 d 2 0.5 0.1 0.7 0.5 0.1 0.7 0.1
2 e 2 0.1 0.7 0.5 0.1 0.7 0.1 0.5
3 f 3 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.2 0.1 0.2 0.1

[[3]]
  A B   C  P1  P2  P3  P4  P5  P6
1 g 3 0.2 0.1 0.5 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.5
2 h 1 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.4 0.2 0.2 0.4
3 i 2 0.5 0.1 0.5 0.1 0.1 0.5 0.7
```

The solution that I have for one single data.frame is this:

```
sampfun <- function(i, l) sample(l[[as.character(i)]], 10000, replace=TRUE)
list.df <- cbind(df, t(sapply(df$B, sampfun, l = ll)))
```

The problem is that I don't know how to implement this solution for use with a list of data.frames.

Many thanks for the help

Note: my *real* list of data.frames has 9,000 elements, and I look to add more than 10,000 columns so the memory and speed up are important.

Comment: are the list indices and the data.frame B columns in the same order? Meaning, 1:3 in the list and B=1, B=2 and B=3 data.frame columns.. in the same order..?

Comment: @Arun, no they don't. the list is order from 1:3 but in the data.frames the B column values could be 1, 2, 3. I've updated my question for clarification

Comment: couple more questions: what's dimension of each of your 9000 data.frames (approximately at least)? What's the length of `ll` in your actual problem? Also, are all elements of `ll` 10000 in length?

Comment: the dimension of my data.frames in the list is variable, the number of rows varies from 2 to 150 but the number of columns is always the same, 3. The length of elements in `ll` is also variable the minimun is 50 and the maximum 330, hopes this help

Comment: what I want to do is to _sample_ in `ll` according to values in `B` column in the list of data.frame and these 10,000 _samplings_ should be added to the data.frames in `list.df` as columns. So, my final list of data.frames should have data.frames with these 10,000 new columns, is this explanation more clear?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I think you missed what I asked regarding the length of `ll`. What does `length(ll)` give? In other words, how many unique elements are there in all of B columns put together?

Comment: sorry @Arun, 398 different elements

Comment: hmm, your problem seems to be a bit huge to fit in memory probably? you've 9000 data.frames, each on average say, 50*3, to which you want to add 1e4 more columns. That means, 9000*50*3 entries multiplied by 1e4 = 1.35e10. Even if we take 1 byte for all storage, this comes to 12.6 GB... Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yeah, that was my first thought, but I can run on a sever-like with 64GB of RAM, I don't know if it would be enough

Comment: Each floating point value takes 10 bytes on average, not to mention that fact that R does a lot of copying of intermediate values, so 12.6 GB*10 is going to overflow your resources.

Comment: Oks, I'll try with another approach, thanks