# R Create dummy datasets based on reference dataset

Tags: r, if-statement, cbind

**Context**

I'd like to build a two dummy survey dataframes for a project. One dataframe has responses to a `Relationship` survey, and another to a`Pulse` survey.

Here are what each look like -

1. *Relationship Dataframe*

   ```
   #Relationship Data
   rel_data= data.frame(
               TYPE=rep('Relationship',446),
               SURVEY_ID = rep('SURVEY 2018 Z662700',446),
               SITE_ID=rep('Z662700',446),
               START_DATE= rep(as.Date('2018-07-01'),446),
               END_DATE= rep(as.Date('2018-07-04'),446)
               )
   ```
2. *Pulse Dataframe*

   ```
   #Pulse Data
   pulse_data= data.frame(
               TYPE=rep('Pulse',525),
               SURVEY_ID = rep('SURVEY 2018 W554800',525),
               SITE_ID=rep('W554800',525),
               START_DATE= rep(as.Date('2018-04-01'),525),
               END_DATE= rep(as.Date('2018-04-04'),525)
               )
   ```

**My Objective**

I'd like to **add columns** to each of these two dataframes, based on conditions from a *reference table*.

The reference table consists of the questions to be added to each of the two survey dataframes, along with further details on each question asked. This is what it looks like

3. *Reference Table*

   ```
   #Reference Table - Question Bank
   qbank= data.frame(QUEST_ID=c('QR1','QR2','QR3','QR4','QR5','QP1','QP2','QP3','QP4','QP5','QP6'),
                 QUEST_TYPE=c('Relationship','Relationship','Relationship','Relationship','Relationship',
                        'Pulse','Pulse','Pulse','Pulse','Pulse','Pulse'),
                 SCALE=c('Preference','Satisfaction','Satisfaction','Satisfaction','Preference','NPS',
                        'Satisfaction','Satisfaction','Satisfaction','Preference','Open-Ended'),
                 FOLLOWUP=c('No','No','No','No','No','No','Yes','No','Yes','No','No'))
   ```

**The Steps**

For each survey dataframe( Relationship & Pulse), I'd like to do the following -

1) Lookup their respective question codes in the reference table, and add only those questions to the dataframe. For example, the `Relationship` dataframe would have only question codes pertaining to `TYPE = 'Relationship'` from the reference table. And the same for the `Pulse` dataframe.

2) The responses to each question would be conditionally added to each dataframe. Here are the conditions -

- If `SCALE = 'Preference'` in the Reference table, then responses would be either `150,100,50,0 or -50`. Also, these numbers would be generated in **any random order.**
- If `SCALE = 'NPS'` in the Reference table, then responses would range from `0 to 10`. Numbers would be generated such that the **Net Promoter Score (NPS) equals 50%.** *Reminder: NPS = Percentage of 9s & 10s minus Percentage of 0s to 6s.*
- If `SCALE = 'Satisfaction'` in the Reference table, then responses would range from `1 (Extremely Dissatisfied)  to 5 (Extremely Satisfied)`. Numbers would be generated such that the **percentage of 1s & 2s equal 90%.**
- If `SCALE = 'Open-Ended'` in the Reference table, then **ensure the column is empty** (i.e. contains no responses).

**My Attempt**

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31542285/cbind-rbind-with-ifelse-condition) previously asked question for the conditional response creation and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17286813/add-columns-to-a-dataframe-based-on-values-from-a-list) one to add columns from the reference table, I attempted to solve the problem. But I haven't got what I was looking for yet.

Any inputs on this would be greatly appreciated

**Desired Output**

My desired output tables would look like this -

*Relationship Dataframe Output*

```
            TYPE            SURVEY_ID SITE_ID START_DATE   END_DATE QR1 QR2 QR3 QR4 QR5
1   Relationship SURVEY 2018 Z662700 Z662700 2018-07-01 2018-07-04 150   5   1   2   2
2   Relationship SURVEY 2018 Z662700 Z662700 2018-07-01 2018-07-04 100   1   2   2   2
3   Relationship SURVEY 2018 Z662700 Z662700 2018-07-01 2018-07-04 100   4   5   2   2
4   Relationship SURVEY 2018 Z662700 Z662700 2018-07-01 2018-07-04 150   1   1   2   2

and so on
```

And the *Pulse Dataframe Output*

```
     TYPE           SURVEY_ID SITE_ID START_DATE   END_DATE QP1 QP2 QP3 QP4 QP5 QP6
1   Pulse SURVEY 2018 W554800 W554800 2018-04-01 2018-04-04   7   1   3   3 100    
2   Pulse SURVEY 2018 W554800 W554800 2018-04-01 2018-04-04   8   5   3   1 100    
3   Pulse SURVEY 2018 W554800 W554800 2018-04-01 2018-04-04   3   1   4   3 100    
4   Pulse SURVEY 2018 W554800 W554800 2018-04-01 2018-04-04   1   2   4   3 100

and so on
```

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far and how was it different from the expected output? 
Will something like `rel_data %>%
  left_join(qbank, by = c("TYPE" = "QUEST_TYPE")) %>%
  select(-FOLLOWUP) %>%
  unique() %>%
  mutate(val = case_when(SCALE == "Preference" ~ "A",
                         SCALE == "Satisfaction" ~ "B",
                         SCALE == "NPS" ~ "C",
                         TRUE ~ NA_character_
  )) %>%
  select(-SCALE) %>%
  spread(key = QUEST_ID, value = val)` work for you?

Comment: Hello Aramis7d your code does not generate the numbers based on conditions listed. Is there a way of modifying it so that the datasets `rel_data` and `pulse_data` contain 446 and 525 rows respectively, and that each question contains numbers based on the conditions listed above?

Comment: yes, it's not the exact answer, but it should get you started. please check [this doc for case_when](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/case_when) .  How is your output different from the expected output?

Comment: Thank you Aramis7d for providing the framework. I have adapted it to my case. If you post this as an answer, I will be happy to upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will something like

`rel_data %>% 
  left_join(qbank, by = c("TYPE" = "QUEST_TYPE")) %>% 
  select(-FOLLOWUP) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  mutate(val = case_when(SCALE == "Preference" ~ "A", 
                         SCALE == "Satisfaction" ~ "B", 
                         SCALE == "NPS" ~ "C", 
                         TRUE ~ NA_character_ )) %>% 
  select(-SCALE) %>% 
  spread(key = QUEST_ID, value = val)`

work for you?

you can modify the `case_when` conditions to fit your need.

Comment: One more question Aramis7d. I am unable to figure how out to generate responses to questions for each `SCALE`, depending on the conditions I listed above. I tried adapting your code, but I'm unable to figure out how to create the full dataset with 446 rows.

Comment: probably try removing the `unique()` from the chain? also, I'd probably drop the `Followup` column before joining the datasets, since it plays no role... not that it matters.

Comment: I tried removing `unique()`. But the issue is that I'm unsure of how to integrate the conditions for responses to each question. I've tried using `sample()` with `prob` argument in place of "A","B" and "C" to generate this list. But I get error messages when I try.